# labelText mixes with freshly typed text in Texfield after losing focus

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Screenshot below shows two textfields with none in focus

[image]

labelText floats as expected when the textfield is in focus whilst text is being typed in the textfield as shown in the picture below

[image]

After you select another textfield and the recently focused textfield loses focus, the label text doesn't remain hanging , but rather collapses into the textfield, thereby jamming up the typed in text. Picture below

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import '../../dashboard_main/animation/fadeAnimation.dart';

class AddCustomExpense extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddCustomExpense({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddCustomExpense> createState() => AddCustomExpenseState();
}

class AddCustomExpenseState extends State<AddCustomExpense> {
  TextEditingController description = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController location = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode descriptionFocus = FocusNode();
  FocusNode locationFocus = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    //Getting the width and height of the device
    double widthOfScreen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double heightOfScreen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Text("New Expense"),
        ),
        body: FadeAnimation(
          delay: 0.5,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              ListView(
                //for listing all the bottom widgets with a vertical scrollable option
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: heightOfScreen * 1.2,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                      boxShadow: const <BoxShadow>[
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black12,
                          blurRadius: 10.0,
                          offset: Offset(0.0, 10.0),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        addExpenseDescription(widthOfScreen),
                        addLocation(widthOfScreen)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  addExpenseDescription(widthOfScreen) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 35,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: widthOfScreen * 0.9,
                  child: TextFieldWidget(
                    hintText: 'Description',
                    obscureText: false,
                    prefixIconData: FontAwesomeIcons.microphone,
                    suffixIconData: FontAwesomeIcons.heart,
                    textEditingController: description,
                    focusNode: descriptionFocus,
                    onChanged: (String e) {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            color: Colors.white,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  addLocation(widthOfScreen) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 35,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: widthOfScreen * 0.9,
                  child: TextFieldWidget(
                    hintText: 'Location',
                    obscureText: false,
                    prefixIconData: Icons.location_on_outlined,
                    suffixIconData: FontAwesomeIcons.heart,
                    textEditingController: location,
                    focusNode: locationFocus,
                    onChanged: (String e) {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            color: Colors.white,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextFieldWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final IconData prefixIconData;
  final IconData suffixIconData;
  final bool obscureText;
  final void Function(String) onChanged;
  final FocusNode focusNode;
  final TextEditingController textEditingController;
  const TextFieldWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.hintText,
      required this.prefixIconData,
      required this.suffixIconData,
      required this.obscureText,
      required this.onChanged,
      required this.focusNode,
      required this.textEditingController})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      onChanged: onChanged,
      obscureText: obscureText,
      controller: textEditingController,
      cursorColor: Colors.red,
      focusNode: focusNode,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        fontSize: 13.0,
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        focusColor: Colors.white,
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        labelText: hintText,
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        alignLabelWithHint: true,
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 9),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          prefixIconData,
          size: 20,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



Flutter Version: 3.0.5
```

Comment: What is happening here: `floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.` ?

Comment: Set `FloatingLabelBehavior.always` to remain that right there

Comment: Can you include full widget with two textFiled that will reproduce the error

Comment: @mohammadesmaili I still get the same output after this change

Comment: @RobertSandberg ```floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always```

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I just did as you requested. full widget with two textFields that reproduce the error. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here the textFiled is getting fixed height from parent which is not enough for `TextFieldWidget`, Therefore it shrinks down and overlap with text.

```dart
child: Column(
  // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: 35, //here is the issue
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: widthOfScreen * 0.9,
            child: TextFieldWidget(
```

You can remove the fixed height and reduce the top padding